# EntityFramework 7 Unit Testing Calls to Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-core

I am currently working in EF Core and I am using in Memory for Unit Testing.

I have couple of Methods calling Stored Procedure.

I would like to know two things

1. How I can add Stored Procedure for EF Core thru migration Script?
2. How you use In Memory for Unit Testing methods calling Stored Procedure. 
   Or Let me know the Alternatives.

Cheers

Comment: Stored procedure support is not available in EF core yet. See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/245